# Android billing 6 enter in initiatePurchase function and do nothing after it

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm new using Android billing. I'm implementing an activity with 4 consumable shopping options. So I have 4 buttons. When user clicks on any of them, the toast initiatedPurchase(productId: String) appears, indicating that they have entered the function, but nothing else happens after that. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
private fun initiatePurchase(productId: String) {

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "initiatePurchase(productId: String)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        // Define the product details to query
        val productList =
            listOf(
                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(productId)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                    .build()
            )

        // Create query parameters
        val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList).build()

        // Query product details
        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                if (productDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    // Extract the product details
                    val productDetails = productDetailsList[0]

                    // Get the price of the product
                    val price = productDetails.getOneTimePurchaseOfferDetails()?.getFormattedPrice()

                    // Update the corresponding TextView with the price
                    when (productId) {
                        PRODUCT_ID_1 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price1).text = price
                        PRODUCT_ID_2 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price2).text = price
                        PRODUCT_ID_3 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price3).text = price
                        PRODUCT_ID_4 -> findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price4).text = price
                    }

                    // Create BillingFlowParams using the product details
                    val productDetailsParamsList =
                        listOf(
                            BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                                .build()
                        )

                    val billingFlowParams =
                        BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
                            .build()

                    // Launch the billing flow
                    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this@Purchase, billingFlowParams)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error " + billingResult.debugMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `setOfferToken` for billing flow params.
Similar to below,

```
BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                         .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                                         .setOfferToken(offerToken)
                                         .build()
```

You can offertoken as below

```
productDetails.getSubscriptionOfferDetails().get(0).getOfferToken()
```